# Conditional include of CSS, but not as last (or first) CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reveal.js

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900426/conditional-include-of-css) adds a CSS conditionally as the last CSS link (effectively overwriting all others), with this javascript:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="website/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="website/reveal/css/reveal.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="website/reveal/css/theme/simple.css" id="theme">
<!-- Conditionally add <link rel="stylesheet" href="website/reveal/css/print/pdf.css"> -->
<script type="text/javascript">
if (...) {
    var lnk = document.createElement('link');
    lnk.type='text/css';
    lnk.href='website/reveal/css/print/pdf.css';
    lnk.rel='stylesheet';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(lnk);
}
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="website/highlight/highlight.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="website/optaplannerPresentation.css">
```

The problem is: It adds it as the last CSS link, overwriting the later 2 CSS files (including highlight.css). **Is there a way to add it after the `simple.css`, but before the `highlight.css`?**

Comment: did you try to load highlight.css using js too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options for you:

1. If the condition you're testing is using information immediately available and your script element doesn't use `async` or `defer`, this could be one of the rare cases where `document.write` is a reasonable option:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="website/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="website/reveal/css/reveal.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="website/reveal/css/theme/simple.css" id="theme">
   <!-- Conditionally add <link rel="stylesheet" href="website/reveal/css/print/pdf.css"> -->
   <script type="text/javascript">
   if (...) {
       document.write('<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="website/reveal/css/print/pdf.css">');
   }
   </script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="website/highlight/highlight.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="website/optaplannerPresentation.css">
   ```
2. If you're using an `async` / `defer` script, or information that isn't avaialble inline, or you just don't want to use `document.write`, you can still do it: You can find the `link` that adds `highlight.css` via [`querySelector`](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-parentnode-queryselector) using an [attribute-ends-with selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors), then use its [`parentNode`](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-node-parentnode) and the parent's [`insertBefore`](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-node-insertbefore) to insert the new `link` in front of it.

   ```
   var lnk = document.createElement('link');
   lnk.type='text/css';
   lnk.href='website/reveal/css/print/pdf.css';
   lnk.rel='stylesheet';
   var highlight = document.querySelector('link[href$="highlight.css"]');
   highlight.parentNode.insertBefore(lnk, highlight);
   ```

   `querySelector` works in all modern browsers, and also IE8. It returns the first element that matches the CSS selector you give it. (There's also `querySelectorAll`, which returns a list of all matching elements.)

   To do that, though, your code must be **after** the `link` for `highlight.css` (unless it's running `async` or in some event handler):

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="website/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="website/reveal/css/reveal.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="website/reveal/css/theme/simple.css" id="theme">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="website/highlight/highlight.css">
   <!-- Conditionally add <link rel="stylesheet" href="website/reveal/css/print/pdf.css"> -->
   <script type="text/javascript">
   if (...) {
       var lnk = document.createElement('link');
       lnk.type='text/css';
       lnk.href='website/reveal/css/print/pdf.css';
       lnk.rel='stylesheet';
       var highlight = document.querySelector('link[href$="highlight.css"]');
       highlight.parentNode.insertBefore(lnk, highlight);
   }
   </script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="website/optaplannerPresentation.css">
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Because JavaScript not executes with page rendering, so you need to add a place holder and then replace:

```
function changeCSS(cssFile) {
    document.getElementById('stylesheetReplace').href='cssFile';
}
```

and placeholder for css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="website/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="website/reveal/css/reveal.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="website/reveal/css/theme/simple.css" id="theme">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="" id="stylesheetReplace>
```

Comment: No, that's not necessary at all.